# JPanel GridBagLayout to GridPane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, javafx

I'm currently trying to migrate an application to JavaFX (It's actually partially using AWT) and while switching JPanels with border layouts to BorderPanes is fairly easy, I'm having quite some trouble figuring out on how to do that with the GridBagLayout and GridPanes. (I never used this Layout in Swing before)
In my code, the GridBagLayout is used 2 times (and I'm not sure if this is auto generated Code):

```
JPanel bottomMessagePanel = new JPanel();
bottomMessagePanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
bottomMessagePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
bottomMessagePanel.add(someJComponent, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, .35, 1, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
bottomMessagePanel.add(someOtherJComponent, new GridBagConstraints(1, 0, 1, 1, .65, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
```

and

```
JPanel stepPanel = new JPanel();
stepPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
stepPanel.add(someJComponent, new GridBagConstraints(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.EAST, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
stepPanel.add(someOtherJComponent, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.EAST, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
stepPanel.add(some3rdJComponent, new GridBagConstraints(2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.EAST, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
```

How would I do this using a JavaFX GridPane?
Don't worry about converting those JComponents, since I already converted those...

Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You specify the `GridBagConstraints`  passing the values to the constructor.

```
GridBagConstraints(
        int gridx,
        int gridy,
        int gridwidth,
        int gridheight,
        double weightx,
        double weighty,
        int anchor,
        int fill,
        Insets insets,
        int ipadx,
        int ipady)
```

Let's describe how to use the equivalents of those parameters in JavaFX:

```
Node node = ...
GridPane gridPane = ...
```

#### gridx, gridy, gridwidth, gridheight

Usually you use the appropriate `add` method of `GridPane` to specify these values. They are called `columnIndex`, `rowIndex`, `columnSpan` and `rowSpan` in JavaFX. If `columnSpan` and `rowSpan` are 1, it suffices to use the `add` method taking 3 parameters:

```
gridPane.add(node, gridx, gridy);
```

If one of the `columnSpan`/`rowSpan` is greater, you can use a overloaded version of the method:

```
gridPane.add(node, gridx, gridy, gridwidth, gridheight);
```

#### weightx, weighty

Those do not have a direct equivalent. Instead you'd need to define this for a whole row/column by using `percentWidth` and `percentHeight` of the [`ColumnConstraints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/ColumnConstraints.html) and the [`RowConstraints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/RowConstraints.html) (that is unless you're satisfied with the standard layout).

Row and column constraints are added to the [`columnConstraints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#getColumnConstraints--) and the [`rowConstraints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#getRowConstraints--) lists.

#### anchor

You can use the `halignment`/`valignment` properties of the `ColumnConstrants`/`RowConstraints` for this or specify this for the individual node using `GridPane.setHalignment` and `GridPane.setValignment`:

```
GridPane.setHalignment(node, HPos.LEFT);
GridPane.setValignment(node, VPos.TOP);
```

#### fill

The equivalent of this is either setting the `fillHeight` and `fillWidth` values of row and column constraints of specifying this for individual node using `GridPane.setFillWidth` and `GridPane.setFillHeight`:

```
GridPane.setFillWidth(node, Boolean.FALSE);
GridPane.setFillHeight(node, Boolean.FALSE);
```

The default value is `true` for these properties.

#### insets

You can specify this by using `GridPane.setMargin`. If you're using `0` for all values, you don't need to specify this.

```
GridPane.setMargin(node, new Insets(top, right, bottom, left));
```

#### ipadx, ipady

There is no equivalent for this in JavaFX.

---

There are `static` `setConstraints` methods allowing you to set multiple constraints at once, e.g.

[`setConstraints(Node child, int columnIndex, int rowIndex, int columnspan, int rowspan, HPos halignment, VPos valignment, Priority hgrow, Priority vgrow, Insets margin)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#setConstraints-javafx.scene.Node-int-int-int-int-javafx.geometry.HPos-javafx.geometry.VPos-javafx.scene.layout.Priority-javafx.scene.layout.Priority-javafx.geometry.Insets-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This helps me a lot! Could you add a code example for one of the components?

Comment: @RoiEX You should be able to find some examples here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY118  and here http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javafx/2121/layouts/8190/gridpane#t=201609091533512884648 as well as in the javadoc...

Comment: Note that the `hgrow` and `vgrow` properties, which can be set either on individual nodes via static methods, or on `ColumnConstraints` or `RowConstraints`, respectively, provide somewhat similar functionality to `weightx` and `weighty`. Instead of a continuous scale of values, however, they take just three values: `NEVER` (equivalent to `weightx=0`), `ALWAYS` (equivalent to `weightx` being the max of all `weightx` in the layout), and `SOMETIMES` (equivalent to `weightx` being equal to some fixed value between 0 and the max).

Comment: GridPane offers a static method `setConstraints` similar to the swing add method... You might want to edit your answer a little bit...

Comment: @RoiEX: Using primitive here doesn't help. It just leads to unnecessary autoboxing resulting in the same objects being passed as parameter.

Comment: @fabian AFAIK Boolean.FALSE just retuns the primitive type. Also the method is accepting the primitive type as param

Comment: @RoiEX: no: see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#FALSE and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#setFillHeight-javafx.scene.Node-java.lang.Boolean- ; note the types start with a uppercase letter, not with the lowercase letter, like primitives... And this method is not accepting the primitive type. If it looks like it does, this is only the case, since the value is converted via autoboxing. If you'd compare those 2 in bytecode, you'd see one uses the field and the other calls `Boolean.valueOf(false)`.